# Why is there so much space in LI

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="patTest">
    <ul id="patTestUL">
        <li>
            <div class="dvInnerLI">
                <span class="spnImgLI"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span class="spnTextLI">It is a great medical group; staff is very accommodating to patient needs.</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="dvInnerLI">
                <span class="spnImgLI"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span class="spnTextLI">@WG has the nicest doctors & staff! #A+.</span>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="dvInnerLI">
                <span class="spnImgLI"><img src="theImages/leftQuote.png" alt="Quote" style="width: 15px; height: 15px; padding-right: 10px;" /></span>
                <span class="spnTextLI">Thanks @WG #Yonkers in & out in 15 minutes to have my blood taken. The nurse was fabulous, too!</span>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

#patTestUL {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}
#patTestUL li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.dvInnerLI {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 98%;
    text-align: center;
}
.spnImgLI {
    width: 20%;
    text-align: right;
}
.spnTextLI {
    color: #000000;
    width: 76%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CEE9F6;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

[image]

Trying to figure out where is there so much space between the text and the blue line above.

`leftQuote` image:

[image]

How do I modify so that the space above and below the blue line are the same?

Source shows this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you left some code out. This is what the code you posted so far generates http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e4ytP/.

Comment: Looks like `.spnImgLI` is told to get it's width from both the CSS and the inline CSS.  That may adjust to the larger width

Comment: Yeah, I'm [not seeing that problem](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ2ed/) with the code you've posted.

Comment: We probably aren't seeing the problem because we don't have access to the image he's using, and thus can't replicate his code exactly.

Comment: Image has been posted.

Comment: It seems all the LI takes the height of the max-height of one of the LI

Comment: Might be browser dependent. On Chrome [I don't see that spacing](http://jsfiddle.net/yQ2ed/1/), even with the updated image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That blue line is coming from a `border-bottom` property on your `spnTextLI` class.  The reason it is so close to the above text is because the border is coming from the div that that text is inside.

If you increase the `padding-bottom` property of your `spnTextLI` class, the border will be pushed further away from the text above it.

Comment: I am trying decrease the space

Comment: @SiKni8 http://jsfiddle.net/e4ytP/1/ - I can't seem to replicate the issue.  Is it still broken on that Fiddle?

Comment: It seems all the LI takes the height of the max-height of one of the LI

Comment: Does it render that way on the Fiddle?

Comment: I am using a library which doesn't seem to work in JSFiddle. Let me double check

Comment: I don't see the bullet... I am guessing it is hidden in my page? It's odd because I never specific the list-style-type.

Comment: I guess you could manually specify the height of each individual list item, although I don't suppose that is the solution you are looking for.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gfv2f/ If you take the script between the `<script>` tag and add the bottom contents in the body section and use JQuery library you will have an idea...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57865/discussion-between-michael-parker-and-sikni8).